# android - how to use onActivityResult from a class

Tags: android, android-camera, android-adapter, android-image

I need to use `onActivityResult` in a class that extends no actiivty.

i use this code in my class, this code calls for camera and the call `startActivityForResult` for proccesing data :

```
    startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

the problem is , I've context in my class, How can I process and use `onActivityResult` in my class?
I don't want to implement `startActivityForResult` in acitivty because it'll be used about 10 times and I don't want repeating codes

how can I do so ?

Comment: well you can either your Interface or an Intent Broadcast

Comment: didnt get 'it'll be used about 10 times and I don't want repeating codes', you can always specify different request codes and differentiate them

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to  implement `startActivityForResult` in all classes .you just have to create a simple `Interface` and implement taht and use the main activity to get activity result and send it to your class  .something like this :

Interface :

```
 public interface IMyClass {
    void getResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
  }
```

main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
  static MainActivity mainActivityOBJ;
  IMyClass requestedClass;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainActivityOBJ=this;
   }

   public void startActivityForMe(IMyClass c , Intent intent,int requestCode)
   {
    requestedClass=c;
    startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);
   }



   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if(requestedClass!=null)
      {
        requestedClass.getResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
      }
  }
}
```

and your class  :

```
 public class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    @Override
    public void getResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     }

     private void StartAC()
      {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.mainActivityOBJ,someActivity.class);
        MainActivity.mainActivityOBJ.startActivityForMe(this,intent,1);
      }
  }
```